# Oracle SQL Analytics Function FirstValue with 'NULL' Values

Tags: sql, oracle, analytic-functions

I have an issue with the analytics function FirstValue:(Syntax:

```
FIRST_VALUE(TAble1.Column2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column3 DESC)
```

Example:

```
Column1     Column2              Column3 
1               A             01/01/2012
1               (NULL)        02/01/2012
1               (NULL)        03/01/2012
```

I want to retrieve one line using the analytics function describe above.

```
Column1     Column2              Column3 
1               A             01/01/2012
```

The issue is that Oracle retrieve 2 lines, one with Null and one other with the value'A' in the column2

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Best Regards

Comment: put your entire query or the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a little old, but posting the answer in case anyone else is Googling and completely stuck.

Oracle's default windowing behaviour is to blame here.

Place

`range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following`

after your `order by` clause

That is,

`FIRST_VALUE(TAble1.Column2 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column3 DESC range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)`

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the position of first non null value in the group differs on column1 to column2.

The combination of first_value function with distinct is not the solution for this type of query.

You can use the row_number function instead:

```
select * from (
    select
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column3 DESC) as rnk,
      FIRST_VALUE(TAble1.Column1 IGNORE NULLS) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column3 DESC) as column1,
      FIRST_VALUE(TAble1.Column2 IGNORE NULLS) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY Column1 ORDER BY Column3 DESC) as column2,
    column3
    from your table
)
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: i would like to use the function firstvalues

Comment: edit the question and put your entire select. the result should have 3 lines, not two.

Comment: it must be because i have a "distinct" option in my query. My select is select  DISTINCT
   TM_TRFATM.SEQGRP,
 FIRST_VALUE(RF_ADRPST.NUMIDVRIF IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY TM_TRFATM.SEQGRP ORDER BY RF_ADRPST.DATDERMDFADRPST DESC) NUMIDVRIF,
 FIRST_VALUE(RF_ADRPST.INDDMGALC IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY TM_TRFATM.SEQGRP ORDER BY RF_ADRPST.DATDERMDFADRPST DESC) INDDMGALC from REFRIF.TM_TRFATM   TM_TRFATM, REFRIF.RF_ADRPST   RF_ADRPST where (RF_ADRPST.NUMIDVRIF=TM_TRFATM.NUMIDVRIF)

Comment: Sorry, too little time to understand the relation with question. Please adapt the query to the example in the question. You can edit your question.